# How to implement a reverse mapping Java using lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, mapping

As far as I know, in Java 8, mapping works as follows

[image]

for example:

```
List<String> objList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
 objList.stream().map( i -> i ). forEach( i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

but my question is: **how I can do the reverse mapping?** like

[image]

so output will be this

```
 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Or it is not possible to do so?

Comment: What do you think your `map( i -> i )` actually does?

Comment: I showed what I understood in the pic

Comment: not exactly a solution but simpler to use apache lib http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138004/1897935

Comment: It effectively does nothing. Remove it and the result will be the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java 8 stream reverse order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)

Comment: @PM77-1 I know if I remove result will be the same. thank u for giving the post

Comment: What is your actual goal? To reverse a `List`?

Comment: how are you?to understand mapping with lamdas

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have another question.

Comment: Let's concentrate on this question, here. Are you trying to reverse the list? Do you understand how `Stream#map` and `Function` work?

Comment: k not really.the picture that I draw reperesent what I have understood from stream mapping and the function that I know works like y = f(x)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you take a look at my latest question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986101/how-to-printout-string-look-like-jagged-array-3-elements-at-a-time-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need your help for something. can you help me plz? or can you come somwehre so we can chat? it is matter of life and death

Comment: @KickButtowski Give me a link for chat.

Comment: @Kick What do you want to talk about? We can use a public SO chat room.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58736/kick-and-soto

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis do you have any idea what this question wants? 1.       Find the asymmetry index given an array of numbers and an integer à find asymmetry index of the array

Comment: @KickButtowski Is there something special about the array? Is it symmetrical (maybe mirrored) in some parts?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the only thing that i know is the question i gave you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58834/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169906/what-is-asymmetry-index-in-an-array-of-numbers take a look at this

Comment: @Kick I'm at work. I'll take a look later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example I accumulate the list into a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

The LinkedList implements [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (Double ended queue) which allows me to append the items in a last-in-first-out (LIFO) order.

I perform the accumulation in the collect method using LinkedList::addFirst which places the items read off the stream at the head of the list.

```
public static void main(final String... args) {

    final List<String> objList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");


    final List<String> reversed = objList.stream()
        .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, LinkedList::addAll);

    //[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]  
    System.out.println(reversed);

}
```

The solution below is OK but I don't like having to close over the original list.

```
public static void main(final String... args) {

    final List<String> objList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");

     final List<String> reversed = IntStream.range(-(objList.size() - 1), 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> objList.get(-i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]  
    System.out.println(reversed);

}
```

Comment: here is too hot and my laptop ain't work. I'll take a look at ur answer later

Comment: if you want me to accept ur answer , plz through some explanation so I can learn. thank u

Comment: Ok I think that I have the tightest version possible. If you need more explanation feel free!

Comment: can u explain this part?        .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, LinkedList::addAll); can u write the way is gonna make more sense like i -> Sustem.out.print(i) plz

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 21, `List` has the [reversed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method, so one solution would be to stream to a `List` (as in your example), and then call `reversed()` on it.

```java
objList.stream().map(i -> i).reversed().forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```