# How to Printout String look like Jagged array 3 elements at a time Java

Tags: java, string

Code:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Izak\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects"
                + "\\ReadElements\\src\\readelements\\elements.txt");
        String s = "";
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
            input.useDelimiter("\\A");
            if (input.hasNext()) {
                s = input.next();
            }

           String[] splitedS = s.split("null");

            for (int i = 0; i < splitedS.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(splitedS[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

my `elements.txt` content:

```
null null -5 160 2 null null
null 75 80 1 75 160 0 null 75 320 1 
null null 155 160 2 null null 
235 0 1 235 80 2 235 160 1 null null
```

my result so far:

```
  -5 160 2  
 75 80 1 75 160 0  75 320 1  <--- String gets printout Like this on Screen
  155 160 2   
235 0 1 235 80 2 235 160 1
```

excepted result:

```
-5 160 2 
75 80 1
75 160 0 
75 320 1 
155 160 2
235 0 1
235 80 2 
235 160 1
```

**but I cannot manage to have my expected result.**

anyone can help me to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please show what the output should look like.

Comment: What kind of pattern is `\A` ?

Comment: @kajacx It's the beginning of input.

Comment: @kajacx take a look at this link https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you explain your answer more? cuz I am not clear about it yet.

Comment: I haven't provided an answer. Also, I don't get the same output as you do.

Comment: no I mean the meaning of \A and how come? r u sure? cuz I copied and pasted and I get the same answer

Comment: See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added a pic of my result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58129/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: Now I do get the same output as you. Can you explain why you expect that other output with the code you have?

Comment: I do not understand your question. I even provided you a pic so you can see my code and my result

Comment: Why do you think that the code you wrote should execute and print your _[expected] result_?

Comment: Just whoever asked for closing this. can tell me why? what is unclear about this?

Comment: I never said my code does, I am just looking for an answer or tip to lead me to my expected result. if you pay attention, I provide result so far section

Comment: What's the logic that maps the contents of `elements.txt` to the expected output?

Comment: I learned that trick of scanning. I just wanted to put the whole file content into a string. get rid of the nulls after and print out the splited string  3 item at the time on screen.

Comment: Then there are other transformations you need to do. Perhaps you should get rid of `"null"`, `split` on one or more whitespace characters, then start printing. Every three prints, add a newline.

Comment: how can i do split on one or more whitespace char?

Comment: `split` expects a regular expression. Look at the `Pattern` javadoc I linked to earlier to construct the appropriate regex.

Comment: This discussion is too long for comments. Please take it to chat.

Comment: so you cannot provide me an answer?

Comment: I did but nobody come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways of doing this:

A. mannually handle things:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(yourPath));

int current = 0;
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    String next = scan.next();
    if(next.equals("null")) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(next+" ");
    current++;
    if(current == 3) {
        System.out.println();
        current = 0;
    }
}
```

or B: let regex do the work:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(yourPath));
String full = scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next().replaceAll("null", "")
       .replaceAll("\\s+"," ").trim().replaceAll("([^\\s]+\\s*){3}", "$0\n");
System.out.print(full);
```

The first doesn't need much comments, the other one, on the other hand...

1. Read whole file into single string: `scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next()`
2. Replace all `null` values with empty string: `replaceAll("null", "")`
3. Get rid of new lines and multiple spaces by replacing any group of whitespaces by a single space: `replaceAll("\\s+"," ")`
4. (Optional) Trim the string so there isn't a space at the start or end
5. (Finally) Take *at least 1 non-whitespace character (but as much as possible)* `[^\\s]+` followed by *any number of whitespaces* `\\s*` and that *three times* `(...){3}` and replace it with *the same thing* `$0` followed by new line ( = add a new line to it)

tl;dr version of 5: add newline after each 3 words.

**Edit:**

To understand step 5 better, you can remove `replaceAll("([^\\s]+\\s*){3}", "$0\n")` to see how the string looks like before this "magic".

It just takes 3 words and replaces them with the same 3 words followed by a newline. By 'word' i mean a group of non-white characters followed by some white characters.

Here is my favourite [regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (I would be lost without it)

**Edit 2:**

I'll put a quick example of `$0`:

If you would want to ban some words, for example `foo` and `boo` and replace then with `****`, you could simply do `text.replaceAll("foo|boo", "****")`

But if wanted to highlight some words (for example `java` and `regex`) by putting exclamation mark before and after them, you have to use backreference `text.replaceAll("java|regex", "!$0!")`

Comment: I am just frozen by your answer. good job man. could you please explain step 5 in more detail?

Comment: I saw it but what $0 means here? so I can consider it as followed by always? why this ([^\\s]+\\s*) not this replaceAll("((\\s+)*)" ,"$0");?

Comment: what is $0 again here cuz it is the answer for me?

Comment: just you said same thing in step 5 what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is get all of the numbers in one list, and then print them three at a time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("elements.txt");
        String text = "";

        ArrayList<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // make a list to store the numbers

        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            fileScanner.useDelimiter("\\A"); // make one large token

            if (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                text = fileScanner.next();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(text); // pattern for integers (negative included)

        while (matcher.find()) {
            allNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group())); // add each match (i.e. number) to the list
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < allNumbers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(allNumbers.get(i));

            if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) { // if index is a multiple of 3
                System.out.println(); // go to the next line
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to combined first Delimiterand second Delimiter in one step?

Comment: can you explain your if statements in your for loop as well?

Comment: I changed things to make it simpler. Note that this solution finds numbers amidst any sort of text and not just the specific scenario you provided. For example: 5sdfs^#Hc f4dfgfdg-8 null 7

Comment: I have a negative number in my list so ur delimiter ain't work for it?

Comment: No, it works, but I'm going to change my answer to use a more intuitive approach.