# How to iterate x times using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I have an old style `for` loop to do some load tests:

```
For (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i) {
  if (i+1 % 100 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Test number "+i+" started.");
  }
  // The test itself...
}
```

**How can I use new Java 8 stream API to be able to do this without the `for`?**

Also, the use of the stream would make it easy to switch to parallel stream. **How to switch to parallel stream?**

* I'd like to keep the reference to `i`.

Comment: what does the phrase *"I'd like to keep the reference to i."* mean if `i` is a primitive?

Comment: and is the test running regardless of the condition?

Comment: Try this `IntStream.range(0, 1000).filter(i->((i+1)%100 ==0)).forEach(i->System.out.printf("Test number %d started.%n", i));`

Comment: Judging by the current code, the test is ran for all `i` values, not every 100. Is this the intention? Do you want to iterate over an index with a predefined step, like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586604/is-it-possible-to-use-streams-intrange-function?

Comment: I just want to notify about the progress each 100 handled elements. I should have done it time wise, but I think it's too late. The answers took it as part of the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000)
         /* .parallel() */
         .filter(i -> i+1 % 100 == 0)
         .peek(i -> System.out.println("Test number " + i + " started."))
         /* other operations on the stream including a terminal one */;
```

If the test is running on each iteration regardless of the condition (take the `filter` out):

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000)
         .peek(i -> {
             if (i + 1 % 100 == 0) {
                 System.out.println("Test number " + i + " started.");
             }
         }).forEach(i -> {/* the test */});
```

Another approach (if you want to iterate over an index with a predefined step, as [@Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) mentioned) is:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 100)
         .limit(1000 / 100)
         .forEach(i -> { /* the test */ });
```

---

*There is an awesome overloaded method `Stream.iterate(seed, condition, unaryOperator)` in JDK 9 which perfectly fits your situation and is designed to make a stream finite and might replace a plain `for`:*

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < 1000, i -> i + 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IntStream` as shown below and explained in the comments:

(1) Iterate `IntStream` range from 1 to 1000

(2) Convert to `parallel` stream

(3) Apply `Predicate` condition to allow integers with `(i+1)%100 == 0`

(4) Now convert the integer to a string `"Test number "+i+" started."`

(5) Output to console

```
IntStream.range(1, 1000). //iterates 1 to 1000
   parallel().//converts to parallel stream
   filter( i -> ((i+1)%100 == 0)). //filters numbers & allows like 99, 199, etc..)
   mapToObj((int i) -> "Test number "+i+" started.").//maps integer to String
   forEach(System.out::println);//prints to the console
```

Comment: This seems to miss `The test itself`, but maybe I'm missing something here...