# Reverse words in a string using lambda expressions

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So I was doing some standard programming interview questions and came across this one:

> Reverse words in a string (words are separated by one or more spaces)

I thought it would be fun to do it using lambda expressions, but I found it difficult to get right and my solution feels kind of unwieldy and hacky. So now my question is: Is there a more idiomatic solution than mine?

```
public static String reverseWordsInString(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Stream.of(str.split(" ")).forEach(
        word -> sb.append(reverseWord(word, !str.endsWith(word)))
    );
    return sb.toString();
}
public static String reverseWord(String str, boolean trailingSpace)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    sb.append(trailingSpace ? " " : "");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order
(also, your split is wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task description is a bit ambiguous. I couldn’t recognize whether you have to *reverse the words* or *reverse the characters of the words*. But here are solutions for both:

```
public static String reverseWordsInString(String str) {
    return String.join(" ", Pattern.compile(" +").splitAsStream(str)
        .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, (a,b)->a.addAll(0, b)));
}
```

```
public static String reverseWordCharacters(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile(" +").splitAsStream(str)
        .map(word->new StringBuilder(word).reverse())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

The first one will reverse the words of a string, thus `reverseWordsInString("this is an example")` will return `example an is this`, the second one will reverse the characters of each word, so `reverseWordCharacters("this is an example")` yield `siht si na elpmaxe`.

Comment: Thanks, your last example was exactly what I was hoping for. Very insightful. :)

Comment: Can do without Pattern as well.

Comment: @AryA the pattern `" +"` reflects the task’s statement “*words are separated by one or more spaces*”. When you pass such a pattern to string’s `split` method, it will still use a `Pattern` behind the scenes. But using `splitAsStream` avoids creating an array containing all substrings.

Answer (score 2):

Following pvg remark [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order) answer this but it’s hard to figure it out from the question itself as it refers to ints.
So based on Venkata Raju answer in the above:

```
Arrays.stream(sentance.split("\\s+"))
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
         .descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Split and collect the result to an intermediate linked list and iterate on  it in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in python where message is the message

```
def reverse_words(message):
    return ' '.join([x[::-1] for x in message[::-1].split(' ')])
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without Pattern or regex. This is to reverse the words in the sentence, and not characters in the words.

```
public static String reverseWordsInString(String str) {
  return String.join(" ", Stream.of(str.split(" "))
                .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, (a,b)->a.addAll(0, b)));
}
```