# Reverse Sort a stream

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I want to reverse sort a stream such as below but getting compile time error as `"The method sorted() in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> o1, <no type> o2) -> {})"`. Can anyone correct this

```
IntStream.range(1, 100)
         .filter(x -> x%2 != 0)
         .sorted((o1,o2) -> -o1.compareTo(o2))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would use streams for something like this.  It would seem to only add a bunch of overhead.

Answer (score 16):

## Explanation

since you're working with an `IntStream` it only has one overload of the [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sorted--) method and it's the natural order (which makes sense).

instead, box the stream from `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` then it should suffice:

```
 IntStream.range(1, 100)
          .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
          .boxed()  // <--- boxed to Stream<Integer>
          .sorted((o1,o2) -> -o1.compareTo(o2)) // now we can call compareTo on Integer
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

However, as mentioned by @Holger in the comments:

> never use a comparator function like `(o1,o2) -> -o1.compareTo(o2)`. It
>   is perfectly legal for a `compareTo` implementation to return
>   `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, in which case negation will fail and produce
>   inconsistent results. A valid reverse comparator would be (o1,o2) ->
>   o2.compareTo(o1)

## Suggestions to improve your code. JDK8

A better approach would be:

```
IntStream.range(1, 100)
         .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
         .boxed()
         .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

why?

- There's already a built-in comparator to perform reverse order as shown above.
- if you want to *guarantee* that the elements are to be seen in the sorted order when printing then utilise `forEachOrdered` (big shout out to @Holger for always reminding me)

or as suggested by @Holger it can all be simplified to as little as this:

```
 IntStream.range(0, 50)
          .map(i -> 99-i*2)
          .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

## JDK9 variant

btw, in JDK9 starting from the code in your post, you can first simplify it via `iterate` to:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i  -> i <= 99, i -> i + 2)
         .boxed()
         .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

With this approach, we can avoid the filter intermediate operation and increment in 2's.

and finally you could simplify it even further with:

```
IntStream.iterate(99, i  -> i > 0 , i -> i - 2)
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

With this approach, we can avoid `filter`, `boxed`,`sorted` et al.

Comment: When we are at usual reminders, never use a comparator function like `(o1,o2) -> -o1.compareTo(o2)`. It is perfectly legal for a `compareTo` implementation to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, in which case negation will fail and produce inconsistent results. A valid reverse comparator would be `(o1,o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1)`, or just `Comparator.reverseOrder()` as you have shown, which does already the job right. By the way, I wouldn’t use `iterate` but rather `IntStream.range(0, 50).map(i -> 99-i*2)` which is more efficient in a lot of cases.

Comment: @Holger really appreciated, learning as always. edited to accommodate your recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

If that is your real code, then it may be more efficient to use `IntStream.iterate` and generate numbers from `99` to `0`:

```
IntStream.iterate(99, i -> i - 1)
    .limit(100)
    .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about simple util such as :

```
private IntStream reverseSort(int from, int to) {
    return IntStream.range(from, to)
                    .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
                    .sorted()
                    .map(i -> to - i + from - 1);
}
```

***Credits***: [Stuart Marks for the reverse util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order).