# Reversing a Queue<Integer> and converting it into an int array

Tags: java, collections, queue

I have a `Queue<Integer>` declared as `Queue<Integer> queue=new LinkedList();`, I need to reverse the elments order in it, and then convert it into an int array. I wrote below code:

```
Collections.reverse((List)queue);
int[] res=queue.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

This code has two problems:

1. the explict casting `(List)queue`;
2. I wonder if there is a one line solution.

So do we have any more elegant way to do this?

---

**Clearification of the problem:**

Whether the queue is reversed is not important. An int array of the reversed elements is what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, **please** don't use raw types (**do** use the diamond operator). Not quite a one liner, but you could first convert to an `int[]` and then use commons lang [`ArrayUtils.reverse(int[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#reverse-int:A-) like

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
// ...
int[] arr = queue.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);
```

You could also write your own `int[]` reverse method that allowed for a fluent interface (e.g. return the `int[]`) then you could make it a one liner. Like,

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And then

```
int[] arr = reverse(queue.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
```

Comment: but this wouldn't reverse the queue.

Comment: @nullpointer True. But, if the goal is a reversed `int[]` then it isn't clear that the queue must also be reversed. In fact, I would assume the queue goes out of scope and the `int[]` is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 8):

No need to get fancy here.

```
static int[] toReversedArray(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    int i = queue.size();
    int[] array = new int[i];
    for (int element : queue) {
        array[--i] = element;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Not a one-liner, but easy to read and fast.

Answer (score 5):

The `Collections.reverse` implies only to `List` which is just one type of `Collection`, you cannot cast a `Queue` to a `List`. But you can try casting it to a `LinkedList` as:

```
Collections.reverse((LinkedList)queue);
```

***Details***:

I doubt that there is a built-in API for reversing the queue. You could still follow a conventional way of doing that using a `Stack` as :

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    stack.add(queue.remove());
}
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    queue.add(stack.pop());
}
```

and then convert to an array as you will

```
int[] res = queue.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

---

On the other hand, if a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) satisfies your needs currently, you can simply rely on the `LinkedList` itself since it implements a `Deque` as well. Then your current implementation would be as simple as :

```
LinkedList<Integer> dequeue = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.reverse(dequeue);
int[] res = dequeue.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

---

> whether the queue is reversed is not important. An int array of the
>   reversed elements is what I need.

Another solution from what others have already suggested is to reverse the `Stream` of the `queue` and then `mapToInt` to convert to an array as :

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
int[] res = reverse(queue.stream()).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

This uses a utility `reverse` suggested by Stuart Marks [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011264/1746118) such that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Stream<T> reverse(Stream<T> input) {
    Object[] temp = input.toArray();
    return (Stream<T>) IntStream.range(0, temp.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> temp[temp.length - i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: You should probably not be using the `Stack` class since it extends `Vector` and is therefore synchronized, which is not needed here and only decreases performance.

Comment: If using a `Deque` it might be more efficient to use `Deque.descendingIterator()` combined with `Spliterators` and `StreamSupport`, assuming only the reversed array is needed and not the reversed `Deque`. The code will be more verbose, however.

Comment: @Slaw It would be sure. Just that the intention of when I wrote the answer was to ensure the original store is reversed, but later the OP clarified that the reversed output is what matters eventually.

Comment: @Marcono1234 actualy, the JVM does away with the `synchronized` blocks within the `Vector` class is its most recent versions when it detects they're are not shared and their aquisition cost is negligible :) but yeah, on principle you shouldn't do that as `Vector` is not recommended to be used anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In *Java8* version you can use *Stream API* to help you.

The skeleton of code like this：

```
int[] reversedQueue = queue.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(() -> new ArrayDeque<Integer>(), ArrayDeque::addFirst, (a,b)->a))
    .stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: It looks like your combiner (`(a,b)->a`) is missing `b` in the result

Comment: @Marcono1234 There is no problem.The third parameter of `Collector.of` method is one `BinaryOperator` it's the combiner function for the new collector. In our code there only one collector,so can't miss any element in collector.

Comment: it does not matter in this case probably since (if I understand it correctly) the combiner is only used for parallel streams. However, you should probably comment that the implementation is not correct, to prevent bugs in the future in case someone uses this code for a parallel stream. It should probably be `(a, b) -> {b.addAll(a); return b;}`.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figure out this one line solution.

```
Integer[] intArray = queue.stream()
            .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, LinkedList::addAll)
            .toArray(new Integer[queue.size()]);
```

the `int[]` version should like

```
int[] intArray = queue.stream()
            .collect(LinkedList<Integer>::new, LinkedList::addFirst, LinkedList::addAll)
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LazyIterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/LazyIterate.html) utility from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) as follows.

```
int[] res = LazyIterate.adapt(queue)
        .collectInt(i -> i)
        .toList()
        .asReversed()
        .toArray();
```

You can also use the [`Collectors2`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html) class with a Java Stream.

```
int[] ints = queue.stream()
        .collect(Collectors2.collectInt(i -> i, IntLists.mutable::empty))
        .asReversed()
        .toArray();
```

You can stream the `int` values directly into a [`MutableIntList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/MutableIntList.html), reverse it, and then convert it to an `int` array.

```
int[] ints =
    IntLists.mutable.ofAll(queue.stream().mapToInt(i -> i)).asReversed().toArray();
```

Finally, you can stream the `int` values directly into a [`MutableIntStack`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/stack/primitive/MutableIntStack.html) and convert it to an `int` array.

```
int[] ints =
    IntStacks.mutable.ofAll(queue.stream().mapToInt(i -> i)).toArray();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

This is one line, but it may not be very efficient:

```
int[] res = queue.stream()
                 .collect(LinkedList<Integer>::new, (l, e) -> l.addFirst(e), (l1, l2) -> l1.addAll(l2))
                 .stream()
                 .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                 .toArray();
```

If you want to be efficient and readable, you should continue using what you have now.

Comment: This does not reverse the queue (or its values)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution using `Stream` and `Collections.reverse()` in **one line of code**:

```
Integer[] reversedArray = queue.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                list -> {
                    Collections.reverse(list);
                    return list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
                }
        ));
```

**OR**

```
int[] reversedArray = queue.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                list -> {
                    Collections.reverse(list);
                    return list.stream()
                            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                            .toArray();
                }
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that creates a reversed array without reversing the queue:

```
int[] i = { queue.size() };
int[] array = new int[i[0]];
queue.forEach(n -> array[--i[0]] = n);
```

The above code is quite hacky due to the impossibility to modify local variables from within lambda expressions. So here `i` needs to be a one-element array, to overcome this restriction.

Note: bear in mind that I've come to this solution just for fun :)