# ZonedDateTime to Date before Java 8 in early Android

Tags: java, android, date, zoneddatetime

I am trying to replace the `ZonedDateTime.toInstant` method because it is only available since API 26 for Android.
But my app is supposed to support API 19.
I want to convert the ZonedDateTime to a Date so i can do something like this:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
final long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

What i want to achieve is the following:
I want to calculate the difference between the current date and another date in Seconds, Minutes, Hours, ... the highest possible unit wins, so i would get e.g. `5 days ago` as result.

Comment: How are you constructing your ZonedDateTime instance? Why can't you just replace it with the code in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: Can't you use Joda Time or the ThreeTen Backport?

Comment: @TheWanderer im getting a string from a json which is then passed to ZonedDateTime.parse(). I will try the ThreeTen Backport and will give an update.

Comment: What does the string from JSON look like? Asking because if it’s like `2019-02-23T10:21:04.791797+01:00`, then `OffsetDateTime` is a still better match for parsing. The question is whether the string has a time zone in it (like Pacific/Pitcairn or ACWST) or only an offset (like `+01:00`).

Comment: The date string is e.g. "2019-02-23T16:50:21Z", so it's UTC.

Comment: I added a solution taking the String instead of a ZonedDateTime. Before that i had to adjust my API library to return the original String instead of the already parsed ZonedDateTime, but it is working! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution (ThreeTen-Backport Library):**
It's working perfectly, i already tried it out on an KitKat emulator.

```
private static final ChronoUnit[] chronoUnits = {ChronoUnit.YEARS, ChronoUnit.MONTHS, ChronoUnit.DAYS, ChronoUnit.HOURS, ChronoUnit.MINUTES, ChronoUnit.SECONDS};
private static final Map<ChronoUnit, Integer> chronoUnitPluralIdMap = new HashMap<ChronoUnit, Integer>() {{
    put(ChronoUnit.YEARS, R.plurals.chrono_unit_years_ago);
    put(ChronoUnit.MONTHS, R.plurals.chrono_unit_months_ago);
    put(ChronoUnit.DAYS, R.plurals.chrono_unit_days_ago);
    put(ChronoUnit.HOURS, R.plurals.chrono_unit_hours_ago);
    put(ChronoUnit.MINUTES, R.plurals.chrono_unit_minutes_ago);
    put(ChronoUnit.SECONDS, R.plurals.chrono_unit_seconds_ago);
}};

public static String getTimeStringUntilNowFromUTC(Context context, String utcDate) {
    Instant now = Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC());
    Instant then = Instant.parse(utcDate);
    for (ChronoUnit chronoUnit : chronoUnits) {
        if (then.isSupported(chronoUnit)) {
            long units = chronoUnit.between(then, now);
            if (units > 0) {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return context.getResources().getQuantityString(chronoUnitPluralIdMap.get(chronoUnit), (int)units, (int)units);
            }
        }
    }
    return "-";
}

public static String getTimeBetweenTwoDates(Context context, String date1, String date2) {
    Instant date1Instant = Instant.parse(date1);
    Instant date2Instant = Instant.parse(date2);
    final long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(date1Instant, date2Instant);
    return getMinutesSecondsString(context, seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

For Android before 26, use the [*ThreeTen-ABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `Date` are *terrible*, really, awful wretched classes. They are laden with bad design decisions and hacks, built by people who did not understand date-time handling. Avoid them. They were entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310 for a reason – actually, *many* reasons.

Avoid these legacy classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

## *ThreeTen-Backport* library

For Java 6 and Java 7, most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

## *ThreeTen-ABP*

That back-port is further adapted to earlier Android (<26) in the *ThreeTen-ABP* project.

I urge you to add this library to your project so you can avoid ever using the tragic legacy classes.

## Conversion

Where you need to interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert back-and-forth between legacy and modern.

In Java 8 and later, convert by calling the new `to…` and `from…` methods found on the old classes.

In the back-port, convert using the `to…` conversion methods found on the [`org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class.

## Elapsed time

Your Question talks about calculating elapsed time.

To count years, months, and days, use [`Period`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Period.html).

To count days (24-hour chunks of time unrelated to the calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second, use [`Duration`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html).

Search Stack Overflow for more info. These classes have been covered many time already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can enable "Support for newer Java language APIs" simply by this gradle configuration:

```
<!-- Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 -->

android {
  defaultConfig {
    //Only required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  // Dependency with the implementation code for the APIs
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/support-for-newer-java-language-apis-bca79fc8ef65

Comment: Tested and it's working! i am using ZonedDateTime in my project which normally works only on api>=26, so i downloaded emulator with api 24 and the project run without crashing!

Answer (score 3):

There’s already a good answer by Basil Bourque. After your comments I thought I could be just a little more specific:

```
public static String diff(String thenStr) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant then = Instant.parse(thenStr);
    ChronoUnit[] units = ChronoUnit.values();
    // try longest units first, they are in the far end of the array
    for (int i = units.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (then.isSupported(units[i])) {
            long diffInCurrentUnit = units[i].between(then, now);
            if (diffInCurrentUnit != 0) {
                return "" + diffInCurrentUnit + ' ' + units[i].toString().toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
    return "0";
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(diff("2019-02-23T16:50:21Z"));
    System.out.println(diff("2019-02-23T20:15:21Z"));
```

Output when running just now:

> ```
> 3 hours
> 36 seconds
> ```

Imports I used:

```
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException;
```

`Instant` doesn’t support coarser units than days (at 24 hours). If you need to be able to return weeks, months or years, just use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `Instant`.

### Question: Can I use java.time on my Android API level?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. In this case import from `java.time` with subpackages.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### A stream?

**EDIT:** @Basil Bourque asked in a comment:

> I wonder if this could be crunched down into a stream, perhaps a one-liner?

It can, but I don’t think it will be an advantage in this case:

```
    return IntStream.range(0, units.length)
            .map(i -> units.length - i - 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> units[i])
            .filter(then::isSupported)
            .filter(unit -> unit.between(then, now) != 0)
            .map(unit -> "" + unit.between(then, now) + ' ' + unit.toString().toLowerCase())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("0");
```

I find the code for taking the array elements backward, `.map(i -> units.length - i - 1)`, a bit hard to read. We need to calculate the difference twice, first for filtering and then for assembling the string result. But it works, and you may go with it if you like.

The double calculation can be avoided with an inner stream pipeline, again harder to read, though:

```
            .flatMap(unit -> LongStream.of(unit.between(then, now))
                    .filter(diff -> diff != 0)
                    .mapToObj(diff -> "" + diff + ' ' + unit.toString().toLowerCase()))
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Interesting approach, looping all `ChronoUnit` enum values. I wonder if this could be crunched down into a stream, perhaps a one-liner?

Comment: It can be turned into a stream, @BasilBourque (and even better after I got rid of the superfluous `try`-`catch`in the code). See my edit. I avoided it at first because I found the code for streaming an array backward harder to read (inspired from [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)).

Comment: Thanks for doing that, @ManuelWa. You may consider posting it as your own answer rather than in the question. I did think that you just might not want to consider *all* chrono units. I see that you found a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Roman Droppa works fine but today (2023) you must change version of library:

```
 compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Dependency with the implementation code for the APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
```