# Java 8+ streams, generics and lambda expressions

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

[ Note: I'm fully aware of the answers provided in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order) ]

I have a set of records that need to be matched/ranked in the context of an other object.

The comparisons needed to determine the ranking score are "expensive" so simply making these classes implement `Comparable` (as indicated in [the other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)) would make it way too slow.

So I came up with essentially (severely simplified code!) this:

```
input
    .stream()
    // Do the calculation and cache the result in a Pair
    .map(record -> Pair.of(record, record.doCalculation(context)))
    .filter(record -> record.getRight() > 0)
 
    // Sort by the calculated value
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Pair::getRight))

    // and do something with it.
    .forEachOrdered(record -> 
        log.info("Record: {} --> {}", record.getRight(), record.getLeft())
    );
```

This sorts the records into an increasing score ordering:

`.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Pair::getRight))`

The problem I need to solve is that I need a decreasing score ordering (i.e. reversed).

Initially expected this to work

`.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Pair::getRight).reversed())`

I checked the `.reversed()` method and it seems to return a comparator (class Collections.ReverseComparator2) that simply swaps the two provided values before feeding it into the original comparator.

This however fails (commandline) with a

```
 incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getRight in class org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<L,R> cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: java.lang.Object
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

In IntelliJ it gives a different error: `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

I suspect it has something to do how streams and generics work together.

My question is that I do not yet understand why this fails.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

NOTE: For now I'm using this ugly workaround:

`.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(p -> p.getRight()*-1L))`

Update:
Solved with the suggestions from [Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%C3%ABl-j)

`.sorted((Comparator.comparingLong(Pair<MyThing, Long>::getRight)).reversed())`

Comment: Did you try expliciting types? There are some corner cases with type inference in lambdas

Comment: @GaëlJ What would that look like? I have tried several ways to put in an explicit cast and failed.

Comment: I found this to work: `.sorted((Comparator.comparingLong(p -> ((Pair<MyThing, Long>)p).getRight())).reversed()` with warnings about unchecked casting.

Comment: Solved: `.sorted((Comparator.comparingLong(Pair<MyThing, Long>::getRight)).reversed())`

Comment: `.sorted((Comparator.<Pair<MyThing, Long>>comparingLong(Pair::getRight)).reversed())` should also work. Or alternatively this: `Comparator<Pair<MyThing, Long>> comp = Comparator.comparingLong(Pair::getRight).reversed();` then use it as `.sorted(comp)`