# Stream API, is there way to iterate descending using instream.range?

Tags: java, java-stream

For example,
`Instream.range(0,10)` - is iterating from 0 index to 10.

`Instream.range(10,0)` - but from 10 to 0 is not working, how to do it using Stream API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)

Comment: @Apokralipsa If possible, I would recommend to avoid sorting in this circumstance since sorting is a stateful operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [IntStream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator))(initialValue, hasNext, next):

```
IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
```

If you are stuck with java 8:

```
IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i - 1).limit(11)
```

Comment: I recommend `i-1` instead of `--i`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate descending stream using range(). Java doc clearly specifies that the steps are an increment of 1. If there was an option to provide a step then we could have. However, there are different ways in which you can achieve the same.

```
IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i >= 1, i -> --i)


IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())


IntStream.range(-10, 0).map(i -> -i)
```

Out of this three using and iterate method would be the best approach.

Comment: "sorted" that's bad, because it holds all values in memory before you can use it

Comment: Yup I know it's bad, I was just listing out the possible ways. I have also added a note at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same set of numbers to be repeated if start/end are transposed then this will replace the ranges if `start > end`:

```
IntStream range(int start, int end) {
    return start < end ? IntStream.range(start,end) 
                       : IntStream.range(-start+1, -end+1).map(i -> -i);
}
range(2,5).forEach(System.out::println);
2
3
4

range(5,2).forEach(System.out::println)
4
3
2
```

If you want the meaning of (startInclusive, endExclusive) to be preserved modify as:

```
IntStream range2(int start, int end) {
    return start < end ? IntStream.range(start,end) 
                       : IntStream.range(-start, -end).map(i -> -i);
}

range2(5,2).forEach(System.out::println)
5
4
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trade-off solution is modify the range value like :

```
    int exclusiveEnd = 10;
    IntStream.range(0, exclusiveEnd).forEach((i) -> {
        System.out.println(exclusiveEnd - 1 - i);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` after `range` to calculate new value:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i -> 10 - i); // 10, 9, .. 1
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).map(i -> 10 - i); // 10, 9, .. 0
```