# Android: Add item to top of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` of model class with some items in it. How to add new item to first position of `ArrayList` and shift others next to it.

Comment: down voted because question already been answered at; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949690/java-arrays-how-to-add-elements-at-the-beginning

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use this method.

```
arraylist .add(0, object)
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Answer (score 4):

AbstractList declares the following:

```
public void add(int location, E object)
```

So,

```
myArrayList.add(0, myObject);
```

Would add it an the top of the list.